# php не находит драйвер для pdo, хотя в phpinfo он отображается, как установленный

Tags: php, pdo

я новичок в php, пытаюсь получить доступ к базе данных postgre с помощью pdo, но получаю ошибку:

`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-8.1.5-0\apache2\htdocs\backend.php`

При этом в выводе `PDO::getAvailableDrivers()` драйвер отображается:

`Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => odbc [2] => pgsql )`

В php.ini раскомментировал соответствующие строки, ломается программа на этапе подключения к бд.

Запрос выглядит так:

`$mydb = new PDO("pgsql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", "$username", "$password");`

Что я раскомментировал в ini:

`extension=pdo_pgsql`

Ума не приложу, в чем может быть проблема, буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Судя по забугорному стаку (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085039/postgresql-pdoexception-with-message-could-not-find-driver), проблема может быть в том, что в php.ini должно быть ещё
`extension=pgsql`